# Can I use Bitnami Helm Chart to deploy Redis Stack?

Tags: node.js, kubernetes-helm, redis

**Background**
Currently, I am deploying a redis container using the [redislabs/redismod] (https://hub.docker.com/r/redislabs/redismod) image in the same pod as the application (nodejs). We are utilizing the RediSearch and RedisJSON modules to access redis cache. I am now planning to move this cache to its own pod, so that we have a single cache server serving the application hosted in multiple pods behind a load balancer.

**Problem**
I would like to use Bitnami Helm chart to deploy a Redis Stack server. However, Bitnami only supports Redis OSS and not Redis Stack, which includes the redis modules that we need. So, the question is has anyone figured out a way to deploy Redis Stack server using a Helm chart?

**Possible solution**
I found this nice [medium article](https://medium.com/@gerkElznik/deploy-redis-stack-using-bitnamis-helm-chart-d8339453352c) which seems like a potential workaround to what I am looking for but wanted to see if someone has tried this our already and if this solution would be OK for production use.